# Symfony 3.4 returns plain text header with JSON response

Tags: php, json, symfony, http-headers, response

I'm working on a project using Symfony 3.4 and sometimes when I make a request that should return only JSON, I get a response with an HTTP header that looks like plain text. Here's an example response:

```
""HTTP/1.1 200 OKDate: Wed, 01 Mar 2023 07:51:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
Expires: Wed, 01 Mar 2023 07:51:05 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
14c64
{"status":"success","msg":""}
0
```

I believe this is causing issues for my front-end code that is expecting a pure JSON response.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? How can I fix it to ensure that my responses always return pure JSON without any extra header information?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to be able to help you without seeing the code.

But from experience and intuition I'm assuming you're passing the `render` method to the **Response** object like in this example:

```
// This will print the headers like in your result
$response = new Response(
    $this->render('path/to/view.html.twig', [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ]),
    200
);
```

You need to pass the `renderView` method instead, like this:

```
// This is what you want
$response = new Response(
    $this->renderView('path/to/view.html.twig', [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ]),
    200
);
```